# Information Processing Letters template

Tags: templates, journal-publishing, journal

So there are two templates posted here https://www.elsevier.com/journals/ifac-papersonline/2405-8963/guide-for-authors    and I'm not sure which gets used.

Also the ifacconf.cls   does not seem to have the same bibliography options  (names and date instead of numbers) and the footer seems to be missing email, while the  CRC journal article style is single column and it seems the majority of the submitted articles are double column  also neither has the  Elsevier decorations.

Comment: For me, this seems to be an off-topic question that should be addressed to "Elsevier" or do I misunderstand your (for me unclear) question?

Comment: Be aware that your question does *not* contain a single question mark! :)